# performance improvements in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: performance, codeigniter, cakephp-2.0

Can anyone attest to performance improvements in the upcoming CakePHP 2.0? I'm facing a decision on a project: to go with current release of CodeIgniter or start with Cake and upgrade later to 2.0.

If it's worth the wait I'd go with Cake but performance would decide for me in the end.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *probably* safe to say CI will come out on tops in raw performance due to it's lightweight nature and lack of overheads, compared to Cake (certainly 1.3), but from what I've read the Cake team are making some pretty large changes, and it is still early days for 2.0.

And as many will attest, the framework is rarely the bottle neck, so you should go with whichever you are most comfortable working with.